# WWfYMP: Bypassing reversible moves

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

This question concerns the theory developed in Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays. The relevant Volume 1 can be found online [here.](https://annarchive.com/files/Winning%20Ways%20for%20Your%20Mathematical%20Plays%20V1.pdf)

I'm unclear about the intuition behind the authors' "Bypassing Reversible Moves" result, the discussion of which begins around page 60. For convenience, this is the result:

[image]

The authors demonstrate that the resulting altered game is indeed equivalent to $G$. I follow their proof, but feel like my understanding of the result is faulty.

In particular, consider what happens if Right's option $D$ in fact has two Left options $A_1,A_2\in D^L$ that are good for Left, with one much better than the other - say $A_1\gg A_2\geq G$. Then in applying the result to $A_2$, it seems to me that we are in effect assuming that Left will respond to $D$ with $A_2$. But what right have we to disregard $A_1$ like this?

Furthermore, it seems to me that after Right's move to $D$ and Left's response to $D^L$, the result assumes that Right will definitely move again in the same component to one of $X,Y,Z,\dots$ - why would this be the case?

Thirdly, I'm not entirely sure why we need the $D^L\geq G$ condition. I would've guessed the result to take form similar to

\begin{equation*}
\text{For any Right option $D$ of $G$, let $A_1\in D^L$ be Left's best response.}
\\
\text{Then it will not affect the value of $G$ if we replace $D$ as a Right option}
\\
\text{of $G$ by all the Right options $X,Y,Z,\dots$ of that $A_1$.}
\end{equation*}
Intuitively, I think of this like when one is evaluating a chess position - to any move of yours, assume your opponent makes the best response, and think about what moves you have in the resulting position.

Thank you for any clarifications in advance. I would find it particularly helpful if some examples were included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about it some more.

Starting with my third concern: the condition $D^L\geq G$ is necessary in order to provide a disincentive for Right to ever move to $D$.

In more detail: by agreeing to play the altered game instead, Left is in effect locking himself into responding to $D$ with some particular $A_2\in D^L$ satisfying $A_2\geq G$. This might seem like a disadvantage to his cause at first (hence my first concern), but it really isn't - it's like saying "If you decide to ruin your position, then I'll commit to playing this particular good continuation." It is evident this isn't much of a concession.

Naturally, Right has no reason to disagree with the alteration either - after all, the only option he has lost is moving to $D$, but moving there would've allowed a response to $D^L$ anyway.

Finally, my second concern was simply due to inattention on my end. All that's happened is Left has committed to responding to $D$ in a certain way. Right has made no commitments.

Comment: You explained this very well. When you replace $D$ with the right options of $A_1$, Left is effectively promising to respond to Right's move of $D$ with $A_1$. This cannot hurt Right, as we only restrict Left's moves, but the fact that $A_1\ge G$ effectively means $A_1$ is such an overwhelmingly good response that it does not hurt Left either. So, it does not matter whether $A_1$ and $A_2$ is used, as they are both overwhelmingly good for left.